mails are going duplicate randomly in nodemailer
import express from 'express'
import { CronJob } from 'cron';
import { runQueryMYSQL } from '../../provider/mysqlProvider.js';
import { runProcedureMYSQL } from '../../provider/mysqlProvider.js';
import constantVariables from '../../utils/constantVariables.js'
import nodeMailer from 'nodemailer';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { generatePOPDF } from '../reports/PO/POPdf.js';
dotenv.config();
const env = process.env;
const router = express.Router();
const { EMAIL_CRON_MIN } = env
var schedulerTime = EMAIL_CRON_MIN

const emailScheduler = () => {
    let jobs = CronJob.from({
        cronTime: `*/${schedulerTime} * * * *`,
        onTick: async function () {
            let query = `SELECT * FROM EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_V WHERE LANGUAGE = 'EN' AND SEND_FLAG = 'N' AND STATUS ='NOT_SENT'`;
            let result = await runQueryMYSQL(query);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
                    service: 'gmail.com',
                    auth: {
                        user: constantVariables.CREDENTIAL.EMAIL_NOTIFICATION.user,
                        pass: constantVariables.CREDENTIAL.EMAIL_NOTIFICATION.password
                    }
                });
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    let mailOptions;
                    if (result[i].EMAIL_CATEGORY_CODE === 'PO_APPROVED_EXT' && result[i].REFERENCE_ID !== null) {
                        generatePOPDF(result[i].REFERENCE_ID, result[i].LANGUAGE).then((buffer) => {
                            mailOptions = {
                                from: result[i].FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                                to: result[i].TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                                cc: result[i].CC_EMAIL_ADDRESS || '',
                                subject: result[i].EMAIL_SUBJECT,
                                html: result[i].EMAIL_BODY,
                                attachments: [{
                                    filename: `PO-${result[i].REFERENCE_ID}.pdf`,
                                    content: buffer,
                                    contentType: 'application/pdf',
                                    contentDisposition: `attachment; filename = "PO-${result[i].REFERENCE_ID}.pdf"`
                                }]
                            }
                            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                                let sendFlag
                                let errorMessage
                                if (error) {
                                    errorMessage = error.message
                                    sendFlag = 'N';
                                } else {
                                    errorMessage = 'Submitted'
                                    sendFlag = 'Y';
                                }
                                let requestForLogs = [
                                    result[i].NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    sendFlag || null,
                                    errorMessage || null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    result[i].FROM_USER_ID,
                                    result[i].FROM_USER_ID,
                                    'InsertOrUpdateEmailNotification',
                                ];
                                let query = "EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_SP"
                                runProcedureMYSQL(query, requestForLogs).then((resultLog) => {
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        mailOptions = {
                            from: result[i].FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                            to: result[i].TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                            cc: result[i].CC_EMAIL_ADDRESS || '',
                            subject: result[i].EMAIL_SUBJECT,
                            html: result[i].EMAIL_BODY,
                        }
                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                            let sendFlag
                            let errorMessage
                            if (error) {
                                errorMessage = error.message
                                sendFlag = 'N';
                            } else {
                                errorMessage = 'Submitted'
                                sendFlag = 'Y';
                            }
                            let requestForLogs = [
                                result[i].NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                sendFlag || null,
                                errorMessage || null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                result[i].FROM_USER_ID,
                                result[i].FROM_USER_ID,
                                'InsertOrUpdateEmailNotification',
                            ];
                            let query = "EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_SP"
                            runProcedureMYSQL(query, requestForLogs).then((resultLog) => {
                                // console.log(resultLog, 'resultLogresultLog');
                            });
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        start: false,
        timeZone: env.TIME_ZONE
    })
    jobs.start()
}


emailScheduler();


export default router;

I am running a cron job to send emails, but some emails are being duplicated randomly. I am unsure whether the issue is with the SMTP server or on my side.
This job runs every 2 minutes, and all the functions are executing properly, step by step. It's sending emails and updating the database correctly. However, in some cases, it is sending duplicate emails to the transporter, although this does not occur in the database updates.

Doesn't look like you do a transaction, so I guess your cron job could not be done when the next starts, hence you pull the same recipient addresses as before. Hard to tell. Add logging to see what's happening. Or check your DB that it doesn't have duplicated recipient addresses.

From the database transaction, I checked, and at 8 PM, only 2 emails were generated. However, on the server side, during the transaction for sending emails, 3 emails are being sent.
